# No implementation was created for Mapper due to having a problem in the erroneous element

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm trying to use Mapstruct to map my classes in a spring boot project.

My dependencies :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>tech.gbeho</groupId>
    <artifactId>redditcloneAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>redditcloneAPI</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JWT dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version> <!-- or newer version -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>1.8</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.8</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't know if the issue is about my dependencies. I tried to change the project's version but all my project was broken.
Maybe the problem provide from my mapper class, I don't know.

```html
@Mapper
public interface SubredditMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "numberOfPosts", expression = "java(mapPosts(subreddit.getPosts()))")
    SubredditDto mapSubredditToDto(Subreddit subreddit);

    default Integer mapPosts(List<Post> numberOfPosts) {
        return numberOfPosts.size();
    }

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    @Mapping(target = "posts", ignore = true)
    Subreddit mapDtoToSubreddit(SubredditDto subredditDto);
}
```

The error message is :

```html
java: No implementation was created for SubredditMapper due to having a problem in the erroneous element java.util.ArrayList. Hint: this often means that some other annotation processor was supposed to process the erroneous element. You can also enable MapStruct verbose mode by setting -Amapstruct.verbose=true as a compilation argument.
```

Someone know how to fix the issue ?

Comment: I would try switching the order of your annotation processing, i.e. put lombok before Mapstruct. I know that has given me issues in the past - Mapstruct was trying to generate its implementation before the getters and setters were generated.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the implement issue but now I have new error message.
"Unknown property "numberOfPosts" in result type SubredditDto. Did you mean "null"?"
The properties in the target flag are unknown. I correctly imported my classes.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what your fix was. Did you put lombok before mapstruct?

Comment: In pom.xml file, I put the path lombok before the mapstruc path.

Answer (score 3):

This **problem occurs when you use lombok adnotation and mapstract together**. For example use Builder or Superbuilder when you extends RepresentationModel class.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder  <-- problem
public class DocumentRepresentationModel extends RepresentationModel<DocumentsRepresentationModel> {

    private String name;
}
```

You need to **remove Builder or separate classes** 1. class extends RepresentationModel
2. entityObject

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface DocumentRepresentationModelAssembler extends RepresentationModelAssembler<DocumentsEntity, DocumentRepresentationModel> {

}
```

Additionaly **in pom.xml you should use lombok-mapstruct-binding**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can download from maven : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok-mapstruct-binding